# Execution blocks because of using System.out.println() in logging inside a for loop?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, system.out

Today we were struggling in a situation when execution blocked ("blocked" - this should be more technical word but at this point i can't figure out) in Java EE project in JBoss EAP alpha version and after sometime there were no more console messages.

Finally we figured that a colleague of mine by mistake placed `System.out.println()` for logging inside a for loop, instead of `slf4j` logger (loop iterates hundreds of times).

**After replacing `System.out.println()` with log.xxxxx() of `slf4j` logger everything was fine**.

I can't understand this strange issue with `System.out.println()`. 
also, Application server was running but unable to serve any request.

Can someone help me to understand this issue and why JBoss was unable to process other requests.

Comment: were you able to reproduce that error, i.e. put it back `System.out.println()` and see what happens.

Comment: yes, it was giving the same pain on replacing slf4j logger from sysout. we struggled for 2-3 hours to detect the issue.

Comment: did you try to attach remote debugger to confirm that you get stuck on that line?

Comment: no, because situation doesn't allow me to debug from eclipse. i have to deploy war in jboss.

Comment: you can still debug 'from' eclipse even if your web application is not running  'in eclipse'. You deploy it to JBOSS and  attach **remote** debugger. Check Eclipse - JBOSS Remote debugging instructions

Comment: Does execution not 'block' if you cast your call to invoke `System.err.println((Object) x);`?

Answer (score 0):

[JBoss remapps the System.err](http://docs.jboss.com/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/logging/util/LoggerStream.html) with a PrintStream that redirects its output to logging.  I would imagine that you are [running into a deadlock](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/729503) between the logger lock and the stream lock.

- `Thread 1` performs logger.log->(locks the logger)->Console Appender->System.err (locks the stream)
- `Thread 2` performs System.err.println->(locks the stream)->logger.log->(locks the logger).

As you can see each thread is grabbing locks in the opposite order.

Impossible you say!  The source code for `org.jboss.logging.util.LoggerStream` doesn't have any synchronized keywords at all. How can it deadlock if the LoggerStream doesn't grab a lock?

Simple, they didn't override every method declared in [java.io.PrintStream](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c98bd523e5f9/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java).  So if you called System.err.println(int) or System.err.println(boolean) you are in trouble.